# Non-Exchange address in Exchange GAL

Tags: exchange-2007

We just made the switch to Google Apps for part of our domain. We disabled the accounts that are now on Google Apps and mail routes correctly. Our problem is that now we have no way of seeing those users in the Global Address List.

So we have these users in our Active Directory, they have no mailbox on Exchange, and we want to be able to see/search for their addresses in the GAL. Is there any way to do this?

This is Exchange 2007, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the contacts in exchange as Mail Contacts.  I believe they show up in the GAL then.

Link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997220%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx

Comment: That's exactly what we ended up doing. Thanks for the response.